# LockoutEnd not set to null when creating a new user in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

To create a new user I'm doing:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser {
    FullName = model.Name,
    UserName = model.Email,
    Email = model.Email,
    LockoutEnd = null,
};
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

However `LockoutEnd` is set to '1/1/1 1:1AM'. How to actually set the value to null?

Answer (score 0):

If we are using the default asp.net core identity, the data type for `LockoutEnd` column is `DATETIMEOFFSET (7)` and it's allow null value so that whenever we don't set a value for it or set it as null, it would be null per my setting.

[image]

Therefore, I'm afraid that we have different setting for column `LockoutEnd`.

```
var user = new IdentityUser
{
    UserName = "tinytest2@xx.com",
    Email = "tinytest@xx.com",
    //LockoutEnd = null,
};
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

I test above code and it worked for me no matter I commented or not commented the line. I also test to set the column to be not null, however, it throws exception when I try to set it to null.

Do you have any default value convert in your `ApplicationUser` model?

Comment: could you pls share more about your details in indentity part, e.g. how you define your application User and how you modify your identity table?